# Customise frappe query report

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I've been trying to make a query_report on frappe.
but it doesn't return the data on the browser.

the console says ***'Unable to handle success response'***

***console.trace() Each data element must implement a unique 'id' property***

this is my sql syntax

```
SELECT
`tabPayment Entry`.`name` AS `id`,
`tabFees`.`student` AS `student id::100`,
`tabFees`.`student_name` AS `name::200`,
`tabFees`.`posting_date` AS `tgl bayar::200`,
`tabFees`.`due_date` AS `bulan inv::200`,
`tabFees`.`outstanding_amount` AS `blm bayar::200`,
`tabFees`.`paid_amount` AS `terbayar::200`,
`tabFees`.`grand_total` AS `total::200`,
`tabFees`.`status` AS `status::200`,
`tabPayment Entry`.`mode_of_payment` AS `mode::200`
FROM
(tabFees
LEFT JOIN `tabPayment Entry` ON (`tabFees`.`student` = `tabPayment Entry`.`party`))
WHERE
`tabFees`.`status` = %(status)s AND
`tabFees`.`due_date` BETWEEN %(from_date)s AND %(to_date)s
```

this is the screenshot of the
[console report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVQaO.png)

that sql syntax is working perfectly on the sql preview software.

Please if you have some answer i will appreciate it....

Comment: I would try to add "Data" specifer to each column like  `tabPayment Entry`.`name` AS `id:Data:100`, `tabFees`.`student` AS `student id:Data:100`,

Comment: hi @TurkerTunali thank you for your response. i'm very appreciate that..
i've tried as you suggested. but it return the same error as before.

Comment: We need to find which `id` field is causing the problem. Does error persist if one of them is deleted?